# label outside a div of the input

Tags: html, angular

I want to put a label for a radio input outside the div where the input is. Something like this

```html
<div class="externalDiv">
    <div class="internalDiv">
        <input type="radio" id="someId"/>
    </div>
    <label for="someId"> Label content </label>
</div>
```

But it's not working this way unless I put the label inside the internal div. How can I make this work?

Edit: What I mean by not working is that when I click on label, the radio button does not get checked.

Comment: how is the question connected to angular? What do you mean with " it is not working"?

Comment: What I mean is when I click on label, the radio button does not get checked. Angular because that's what I'm using. I added the tag so maybe if there some angular specific solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```css
p,
label {
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input {
    margin: .4rem;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Select a maintenance drone:</legend>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey"
             checked>
      <label for="huey">Huey</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
      <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
      <label for="louie">Louie</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```